# Moving to the beginning of line within Vim insert mode

Tags: vim

While typing I realize that I need to move to the beginning of the line. Usually I use <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>I</kbd>. But I am wondering if there is another way to move to the beginning of the line in the insert mode.

Comment: What platform? Mac Linux Windows

GUI or terminal?

Comment: Just to be said, it would certainly be preferable to stick with `<Esc>` then move, insert, replace or whatever. That way your changes will be registred in the undo tree.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> which switches to normal mode for one command. This allows you to do movements, such as:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> beginning of line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>$</kbd> end of line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd> find first y in sentence

Comment: While the question does ask about insert mode only, here's an alternative that achieves the same thing: <C-c>I and <C-c>A, note the capitals.

Answer (score 15):

I will remap some shortcut keys in [my vimrc](https://github.com/marslo/myvim/blob/master/config/vimrc#L469), most of them are cursor moving under the **Insert mode**.

For example, I will use the Emacs-Like (as same as in Linux Terminal) shortcut:

```
map <C-a> <ESC>^
imap <C-a> <ESC>I
map <C-e> <ESC>$
imap <C-e> <ESC>A
inoremap <M-f> <ESC><Space>Wi
inoremap <M-b> <Esc>Bi
inoremap <M-d> <ESC>cW
```

That means:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>: Go to beginning of the line [Normal Mode && Insert Mode]
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>: Go to end of line [Normal Mode && Insert Mode]
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>: Backward a word [Insert Mode]
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>: Forward a word [Insert Mode]
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>: Delete a word (backward) [Insert Mode]

Of cause, vim has default shortcut key for **Delete a word (forward) [Insert Mode]**, that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

Comment: C-w only exists in insert mode, and deletes *backwards* to the beginning of the current (or previous) word

Answer (score 6):

The <kbd>Home</kbd> key works in Vim while in insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

I find this package quite helpful to setup emacs bindings in vim insert mode: https://github.com/kentarosasaki/vim-emacs-bindings

Copying the code from there as suggested by members:

```
" insert mode
imap <C-p> <Up>
imap <C-n> <Down>
imap <C-b> <Left>
imap <C-f> <Right>
imap <C-a> <C-o>:call <SID>home()<CR>
imap <C-e> <End>
imap <C-d> <Del>
imap <C-h> <BS>
imap <C-k> <C-r>=<SID>kill()<CR>

function! s:home()
  let start_column = col('.')
  normal! ^
  if col('.') == start_column
    normal! 0
  endif
  return ''
endfunction

function! s:kill()
  let [text_before, text_after] = s:split_line()
  if len(text_after) == 0
    normal! J
  else
    call setline(line('.'), text_before)
  endif
  return ''
endfunction

function! s:split_line()
  let line_text = getline(line('.'))
  let text_after  = line_text[col('.')-1 :]
  let text_before = (col('.') > 1) ? line_text[: col('.')-2] : ''
  return [text_before, text_after]
endfunction
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers as the linked site might get changed or deleted entirely, rendering your answer useless. Instead please quote the most important parts and provide the link as reference only.

Answer (score -1):

While in Insert mode, the Home key moves the cursor to the beginning of the line. If in Normal mode, "SHIFT+I" moves the cursor to the line's first position, changing mode also to Insert mode.

I note that the Insert mode CTRL+o and :(linenumber) is still a viable means to jump directly another line from insert mode to insert mode, however practical/impractical you could find it. It works.

> $>vim --version VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Feb 21
> 2021 23:02:54) MS-Windows 64-bit console version Included patches:
> 1-2541 Compiled by appveyor@APPVYR-WIN Huge version without GUI.: